# How to update a field in attribute table with values from a list? (UpdateCursor)

Tags: python, arcpy

I have a list which is a range from 1-1423

and I am trying to assign each of those to the field "Name" in a feature class which has 1423 total points.

the error message is: TypeError: argument must be a sequence of values

```
import arcpy

fc = "C:/kdsfdlsjflj/something.shp"
field = "Name"
xlist = list(range(1, 1423))

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, field) as cursor:
  for row in cursor:
    i=0
    row = xlist[i]
    cursor.updateRow(row)
    i+=1'
```

`

Comment: You are obtaining `row` from `cursor` and then re-assigning `row` to an int value from `xlist`. Also `i` is reset to 0 for every iteration of the the for loop and so never changes.

Comment: I think field attribute  must be a list instead of string so it should be like UpdateCursor(fc, [field]) as cursor

Answer (score 0):

When you put a value into `row` variable, it must be a data-structure such as a list or a tuple. I also noticed that every run of the loop you reset your index variable, it should be set outside the for-loop.

This is how it should look:

```
import arcpy

fc = "C:/kdsfdlsjflj/something.shp"
field = "Name"
xlist = list(range(1, 1423))

i = 0

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, field) as cursor:
  for row in cursor:
    row = (xlist[i],) # Inserted into tuple
    cursor.updateRow(row)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as

```
row[0] = xlist[i]
cursor.updateRow(row)
```

This is because row remains a list and the Name field is index zero in row.

If you want to sequentially number I recommend the alternative so the number of features does not need to be know.

```
i=o
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, field) as cursor:
  for row in cursor:
     i+=1
     row[0] = i
     cursor.updateRow(row)
```